# Converting R code to MATLAB code: Stuck at sapply()

Tags: r, matlab, debugging

I have the following R code, which I am trying to convert to MATLAB. (No, I do not want to run the R code in MATLAB like shown [here](http://neurochannels.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-run-r-code-in-matlab.html)).

The R code is here:

```
# model parameters
dt <- 0.001
t <- seq(dt,0.3,dt)
n=700*1000
D = 1
d = 0.5

# model
ft <- n*d/sqrt(2*D*t^3)*dnorm(d/sqrt(2*D*t),0,1)
fmids <- n*d/sqrt(2*D*(t+dt/2)^3)*dnorm(d/sqrt(2*D*(t+dt/2)),0,1)
plot(t,ft*dt,type="l",lwd=1.5,lty=2)

# simulation
#    
# simulation by drawing from uniform distribution
# and converting to time by using quantile function of normal distribution
ps <- runif(n,0,1)                
ts <- 2*pnorm(-d/sqrt(2*D*t))     
sumn <- sapply(ts, FUN = function(tb) sum(ps < tb))
lines(t[-length(sumn)],sumn[-1]-sumn[-length(sumn)],col=4)
```

And the MATLAB code I have done so far is

```
% # model
ft = (n*d)./sqrt(2*D.*t.^3).*normpdf(d./sqrt(2*D.*t),0,1);
fmids = (n*d)./sqrt(2*D*((t+dt)./2).^3).*normpdf(d./sqrt(2*D.*((t+dt)./2)),0,1);
figure;plot(t,ft.*dt);

% # simulation
% #    
% # simulation by drawing from uniform distribution
% # and converting to time by using quantile function of normal distribution
ps = rand(1,n);                
ts = 2*normcdf(-d./sqrt(2*D*t));
```

So, here is where I am stuck. I don't understand what function `sumn = sapply(ts, FUN = function(tb) sum(ps < tb))` does and where the parameter '`tb`' came from. It is not defined in the given R code as well.

Could anyone tell me what the equivalent of that function R code is in MATLAB?

**[EDIT 1: UPDATE]**

So, based on the comments from @Croote, I came up with the following code for the function defined in `sapply()`

```
sumidx  = bsxfun(@lt,ps,ts');
summat  = sumidx.*repmat(ps,300,1);
sumn    = sum(summat,2);
sumnfin = sumn(2:end)-sumn(1:end-1);
plot(t(1:length(sumn)-1),sumnfin)
```

However, I am not getting the desired results. The curves should overlap with each other: *the blue curve is correct, so the orange need to overlap with the blue curve*.

[image]

What am I missing here? Is R's `pnorm()` equivalent to MATLAB's`normcdf()` as I have done here?

**[EDIT 2: FOUND THE BUG!]**

So, after fiddling around, I discovered that I all I had to do was obtain the number of occurrences of `tb < pb`. The line `summat  = sumidx.*repmat(ps,300,1)` is not supposed to be there.  After removing that line and keeping `sumn    = sum(sumidx,2);`, I get the desired result.

[image]

Comment: `sapply` applies the function defined as `function(tb){sum(ps < tb)}` to the list or vector `ts` and will return a list. Its like a forloop applying a function to each element in a list. Hence `tb` only exists as a variable placeholder in the function being applied.

Comment: So is the function taking one value of `tb` and identifying values in `ps` that are less than that particular `tb` value and summing them. Then repeat the same for the remaining values of `tb`? Or first, it performs the search for all `tb` value and sums them at the end of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

So, based on the comments from @Croote and after fiddling around, I came up with the following code for the function defined in `sapply()`

```
sumidx  = bsxfun(@lt,ps,ts');
sumn    = sum(sumidx,2);
```

And for the plot, I coded it as

```
sumnfin = sumn(2:end)-sumn(1:end-1);
plot(t(1:length(sumn)-1),sumnfin)
```

Finally, I get the desired result

[image]